# Select/Option/value on change using ASP and no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, ms-access, asp-classic, html-select

- I have a webpage that has a form in the middle of it.
- There are a bunch of fields that are filled in, dynamically, with the contents from an Access database.
- In the middle of the form is a select/option/drop-down menu, the contents of which are from the database,  as well.
- When the user, perusing the partial list of database items sees one that they are interested in they select it.
- This causes the OnChange event To fire.

  - This calls a function up in the header to execute.
  - And that function is in JavaScript.
- They were in the problem lies: it creates a variable that looks like this  `"select * from database where IDX=value"` where value comes from the above mentioned select/Option box.
- Without using AJAX (that I do not know) How can I execute that against the Access database?

Once executed  I want the resulting record to be returned in a `RecordSet` Where will be further dissected in ASP with portions of that record than being displayed.

How can I do this? hopefully entirely in ASP? (Alternately a simple instruction of using Ajax with a plug-in of my database name and query would be great!)

I await your responses. Thank you.

Comment: Your title is misleading, I take it you mean, no Ajax, rather than no JavaScript, as the onchange is JavaScript.

Comment: Ifyou don't want to use AJAX, your only other option is to have the onchange event submit a form and cause a page reload. Then in the classic ASP look for the proper Request.Form value, and take it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<%
DIM adoCon, RS
Set adoCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set RS=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
adoCon.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; Persist Security Info=false; Data Source=.; initial catalog=databaseName; user id=user; password=p@ssword;"
%>
<form>
<select name="sel_IDX" id="sel_IDX" onchange="window.location.href='?IDX=' + document.getElementById('sel_IDX').value" >
<option value=''>Select</option>
<%
RS.Open "select * from database where IDX=value", adoCon
  IF NOT RS.EOF THEN
  DO WHILE NOT RS.EOF
    IF Request.QuertString("IDX") = RS("IDX") THEN
      Response.Write "<option value=' " & RS("IDX") & " ' selected > " & RS("IDX") & " </option>"
    ELSE
      Response.Write "<option value=' " & RS("IDX") & " ' > " & RS("IDX") & " </option>"
    END IF
  RS.MoveNext
  LOOP
  END IF
RS.Close
adoCon.Close
 %> 
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Now what would I do given Server = "Fred.net" with loginID/User= "useruser" and password="PWDPWD"? And how do I  keep the loginID/password secure on the client side?

Comment: Oh! aalso consider that the database is called  "database.MDB" and the table is called "tabletable"

Comment: Code inside `<% %>` will not be  visible on client, only html code will be displayed, change your connection string  as per your requirement. refere [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/)

Comment: Color me dense,  but I'm still not getting it. I finally understand the security aspect which is great.  Thanks!  On the client side  I have some HTML code  which in turn calls some JavaScript code that forms some variable.  I then want to  call some server-side code, which then operates upon the databa with the called variable.  Then the database record is returned to the JavaScript code which the either dissects it and displays portions  upon the screen or return to to the ASP code  which dissects it  and displays portions upon the screen.How do I do this? Like I said,  color me dense..